# Regex for the value of an HTML Property

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a load of links that look like this:

```
        <A HREF="http://www.taboola.com/" ADD_DATE="1385139696" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Taboola - Content you may like</A>
```

I want to delete the entire `ICON` and `ADD_DATE` attributes and their values.

I'm using sublime with a regex find/replace but I'm not sure how to write the regex to grab everything in between `ICON="` AND `"`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To grab the attributes of ICON just use the following REGEX, `ICON=\"(.*)"` this will put all characters in between the quotation marks in a variable

Comment: @Xabier: Only if there are no other quotation marks…

Comment: @Xabier this will grab all the text until the final "

Comment: Check my answer with updated solution, the one without "?" may fail at some times

Comment: @minitech .There can't be any other quotation marks in a well formed data image attribute.

Comment: @Xabier: I mean afterwards. `.*` grabs as many characters as possible as long as it ends before *a* quotation mark; `.*?` is more correct.

Comment: @minitech Yes, your are right .*? is more correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (escaping quotes as necessary):

```
ICON="[^"]*"
```

The reason `ICON=\"(.*)"` won't work is that regex can 'be greedy' in what it takes. This means that if it can match more of the string to satisfy the pattern it will.

You can either specify a non greedy search, such as `ICON=".*?"` or explicitly declare matches on atoms that are not quotes as in the above answer.